# Error Parameter is not an int - issue loading from sdf

Tags: sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Trying to load an int with a model plugin.
sdf:

```
<plugin name="catvehicle_sim" filename="libcatvehicle_sim.so">
    <robotNamespace>/</robotNamespace>
    <speed>20</speed>
</plugin>
```

Try to access with:

```
 speed = _sdf->GetElement("speed")->GetValueInt();
```

gives error:

```
Error [Param.cc:514] Parameter [speed] is not an int
```

Using Gazebo 1.5 with ROS groovy. What is the correct way to do this? I could just convert from a string but it seems like I am missing something easy. Should I be using attributes?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3730/error-parameter-is-not-an-int---issue-loading-from-sdf/) by [FiliusFortunae](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/412/filiusfortunae/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 43 on 2013-07-23

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2013-07-23**:
This happened to me as well, not only for int, bool as well. I know getting the value as double works, and then you can change it to int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I can replicate the problem with Gazebo 1.5.0 in Groovy and in standalone Gazebo 1.8.6.  As @AndreiHaidu suggests, retrieving it as a double is a reasonable workaround.  E.g.:

```
int speed = (int)_sdf->GetElement("speed")->GetValueDouble();
```

This problem is not present (i.e., the call to retrieve the parameter as an int works) in gazebo 1.9.x with sdformat 1.4.4.  So it would seem that the bug was fixed during the extraction of the SDF parser into the sdformat package.

Given the relative ease of the workaround, we're unlikely to fix this bug in older versions.

---

Originally posted by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) with karma: 1414 on 2013-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0